# Problems with macports and patch on OSX 10.6.8

Tags: macos, macports

I can't seem to install anything with MacPorts. Problems inevitably arise when MacPorts gets to the stage where it tries to apply patches. It croaks because apparently `/usr/bin/patch` has a security patch that prevents itself from patching upwards in the directory tree. A typical error message:

```
:info:patch /usr/bin/patch: **** rejecting file name with ".." component: ../libunwind/include/libunwind.h
```

I see some various bug reports on this issue such as https://trac.macports.org/ticket/29871 and https://trac.macports.org/ticket/29813, but no real solutions.

Is there a patch to patch?

Comment: Because it is a security problem and likely affects very few ports, it appears the MacPorts project approach is to fix the problem ports as they are discovered.  If you haven't already, check to make sure whether there is an issue opened for the port you're having a problem with and, if not, open a new issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not use Macports (so I cannot test this possible solution), but perhaps you could try installing the GNU version of `patch`.  There is indeed a [portfile](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/devel/gpatch/Portfile) for it within Macports.  It installs as `gpatch`, but you could easily create a symbolic link such that `/opt/bin/patch -> /opt/bin/gpatch`. Additionally, you will need to ensure that `/opt/bin` appears before `/usr/bin` in your path.

Although the portfile requires a patch to be applied, it fortunately does not use any `..` path components.

It appears as though this [security patch](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/patch.git/commit/?id=685a78b6052f4df6eac6d625a545cfb54a6ac0e1) originated in February of 2011.  As 2.6.1 predates this, I believe this method should work.

Comment: Altering anything in `/usr/bin` on OS X is almost always a bad idea.  However, if you wanted to temporarily work around the problem just to install this one port until the port is patched, you could install the MacPorts `gpatch`.  However, be extremely careful not to overwrite the Apple-supplied `patch` in `/usr/bin`.  And MacPorts installs to `/opt/local/bin`.  So something like this should work (untested!):  `sudo mv /usr/bin/patch /usr/bin/patch-SAVED; sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/gpatch /usr/bin/patch; sudo port install xxxx; sudo mv /usr/bin/patch-SAVED /usr/bin/patch`

Comment: Actually, I had to hit /usr/bin/patch rather than /opt/local/bin/patch because apparently /opt/local/bin/port explicitly uses /usr/bin/patch rather than patch. I made a new script that temporarily saves /usr/bin/patch, symlinks /usr/bin/patch to the insecure gpatch, runs port, and then restores /usr/bin/patch to the original.

Comment: Yes, that's what I suggested.  MacPorts is very careful to specify exactly what build tools it uses.